# npm csv-parse not reading all rows

Tags: javascript, csv, filereader, node-csv-parse

I'm trying to read a CSV using [csv-parse](https://csv.js.org/parse/), but the final line isn't being read.
My code:

```
const handleFiles = event => {
  const f = event.target.files[0];
  const parser = CsvParse({delimiter: ',', columns: true});
  parser.on('readable', function(){
    console.log('readable');
    let record;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-cond-assign
    while (record = parser.read()) {
      console.log(record);
    }
  });
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function() {
    return function(e) {
      console.log('Writing');
      parser.write(e.target.result);
    };
  })(f);

  reader.readAsText(f);
};
```

The input:

```
Letter,Number
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

The output:

```
Writing
readable
{Letter: "A", Number: "1"}
readable
{Letter: "B", Number: "2"}
```

Why is C3 not being read?
And why is "readable" being printed twice? I have a feeling I'm not understanding csv-parse correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I was missing `parser.end();` after `parser.write(e.target.result);` The last row was read correctly after adding that.